# How do I turn text input to drop down selection that changes table rows?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to have a drop down selection that changes table rows.

Right now I have it so that user can type their input and it dynamically changes the table rows. But I want a drop down selection.

This is what I have so far...

```
<div class="inputs">
      <input type="text" id="contractInput" onkeyup="contractFunction()">
</div>

<table id="myTable">
      <tr>
         ...some table data...
      </tr>

      <tr>
         ...some table data...
      </tr>

      <tr>
         ...some table data...
      </tr>
</table>
```

And here is the javascript code

```
function contractFunction() {
    var input, filter, table, tr, td1, td2, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("contractInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        if (td) {
        txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            tr[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }       
    } 
}
```

I tried to have a select tag and have different options and this.value to the function and in the script, change the input variable to the selection but whenever I choose something, it sets the entire table display to "none".

Any feedback is welcomed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

okay I have figured it out. The script is the same. But instead of input tags, I changed to this...

```
<select id="myList" onchange="function()" class='form-control'>
     <option> option 1 </option>
     <option> option 2 </option>
</select>
```

no need to pass any variables